# PyQt - Animations without redrawing everything?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, animation, pyqt

So I'm trying to learn animations in PyQt and throughout all the examples I can find online, they all seem to use the `self.update()` or `self.repaint()` methods to increment the animations. This means basically the code has to erase then redraw the entire widget for every frame, even though much of what I intend to animate is static.

For example the code below, this generates a circular progress pie. The important bit is the `paint()` method under `ProgressMeter` (first class): for every frame in the animation this example paints the background, the actual progress pie, and the percentage indicator.

If I change the code to something like:

```
if self.angle > 120:
    # do not draw background
```

then after 120 frames, the background does not get drawn anymore.

This seems terribly inefficient because (logically) the background should only be drawn once, no?

What would you recommend for animations like these?

Addendum: I have lurked a lot on this site to steal examples and code, but haven't posted for a long time. Please let me know about proper etiquette etc if I am not following it properly.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class ProgressMeter(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ProgressMeter, self).__init__()

        self.parent = parent

        self.angle = 0
        self.per = 0

    def boundingRect(self):

        return QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, self.parent.width(),
                             self.parent.height())

    def increment(self):

        self.angle += 1
        self.per = int(self.angle / 3.6)

        if self.angle > 360:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):

        self.drawBackground(painter, widget)
        self.drawMeter(painter, widget)
        self.drawText(painter)

    def drawBackground(self, painter, widget):

        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)

        p1 = QtCore.QPointF(80, 80)
        g = QtGui.QRadialGradient(p1 * 0.2, 80 * 1.1)

        g.setColorAt(0.0, widget.palette().light().color())
        g.setColorAt(1.0, widget.palette().dark().color())
        painter.setBrush(g)
        painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, 80, 80)

        p2 = QtCore.QPointF(40, 40)
        g = QtGui.QRadialGradient(p2, 70 * 1.3)

        g.setColorAt(0.0, widget.palette().midlight().color())
        g.setColorAt(1.0, widget.palette().dark().color())
        painter.setBrush(g)
        painter.drawEllipse(7.5, 7.5, 65, 65)

    def drawMeter(self, painter, widget):

        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(widget.palette().highlight().color())
        painter.drawPie(7.5, 7.5, 65, 65, 0, -self.angle * 16)

    def drawText(self, painter):

        text = "%d%%" % self.per

        font = painter.font()
        font.setPixelSize(11)
        painter.setFont(font)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("#000000"))
        pen = QtGui.QPen(brush, 1)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        # size = painter.fontMetrics().size(QtCore.Qt.TextSingleLine, text)
        painter.drawText(0, 0, 80, 80,
                         QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, text)


class MyView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyView, self).__init__()

        self.initView()
        self.setupScene()
        self.setupAnimation()

        self.setGeometry(300, 150, 250, 250)

    def initView(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Progress meter")
        self.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        policy = QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(policy)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(policy)

        self.setBackgroundBrush(self.palette().window())

        self.pm = ProgressMeter(self)
        self.pm.setPos(55, 55)

    def setupScene(self):
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 250, 250)
        self.scene.addItem(self.pm)

        self.setScene(self.scene)

    def setupAnimation(self):
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimeLine()
        self.timer.setLoopCount(0)
        self.timer.setFrameRange(0, 100)

        self.animation = QtGui.QGraphicsItemAnimation()
        self.animation.setItem(self.pm)
        self.animation.setTimeLine(self.timer)

        self.timer.frameChanged[int].connect(self.doStep)
        self.timer.start()

    def doStep(self, i):
        if not self.pm.increment():
            self.timer.stop()

        self.pm.update()


app = QtGui.QApplication([])
view = MyView()
view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Qt's documentation about QWidget repaint slot says:

*Repaints the widget directly by calling paintEvent() immediately, unless updates are disabled or the widget is hidden.
We suggest only using repaint() if you need an immediate repaint, for example during animation. In almost all circumstances update() is better, as it permits Qt to optimize for speed and minimize flicker.
Warning: If you call repaint() in a function which may itself be called from paintEvent(), you may get infinite recursion. The update() function never causes recursion.*

That should give you an answer about when to use or not repaint or update slots.

About making animations I'd suggest you also to take a look to the [Qt4's animation framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/animation-overview.html) or [Qt5's animation framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/animation-overview.html), which is a really powerful way to animate widgets on Qt.

Comment: Thanks! that  documentation was exactly what I saw earlier to prompt this question. Issue is as it says, both methods erase then redraw the whole widget, but I really don't need that as only a small component of all my objects need to change. In Tkinter, for example (which is what im migrating my GUI from), I can create a canvas but just use a self.object.move() method to move only what I need animated. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3627191 You're welcome, but you haven't marked the answer as accepted, anything else is still unclear to you?

Comment: my bad - upvoted but didn't realize I needed to click the checkmark as well :)